# FileUpload: keep filenames when showing validation errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have the following file-upload code in C# using Asp.Net MVC. The problem is that when validation errors are shown, all the files chosen by the user are lost (input boxes are cleared). Is it possible to keep the input filenames in their original ordering without using javascript? What's the simplest approach?

**Controller code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    //check for errors: if errors, ModelState.AddModelError(...);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View(files);
    }
    else {
        //..........
    }
}
```

**View snippet**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Uploader", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("1")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("2")
    </div>
    //and 2 more file input fields

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: There is no simple way to do that.  You'd need to store them on the server, or switch to JS validation.

Comment: if i store them on the server, how to send them back to the client?

Comment: You don't; you would display their names in read-only fields.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. I believe not even by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In postback you can not retain same local path which will remain in  type="file".

to do this think there are two way
1) in your current code if you find any file attached then save on server and maintain some flag in hidden field and hide/show your file control with text box( having only filename)
 and send it back to browser. Then on next valid submit take that file name that you have already saved. and do your process.

2) On submit of form, copy(DOM copy) all your html control(file ,textbox, hidenfield ect..) in one iframe and submit that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is still in search of a possibility, here is the work around that worked for me. I'm using MVC5. The idea is to use a session variable. I got the idea from [ASP.Net Form](https://forums.asp.net/t/1895657.aspx?ASP%20NET%20MVC%204%20Browser%20looses%20uploading%20File%20after%20Postback).

My Model/ViewModel (only relevant properties):

```
public partial class emp_leaves
    {
        public string fileNameOrig { get; set; }
        public byte[] fileContent { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller (HttpPost):
//Check

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(emp_leaves emp_leaves)
{
    if (emp_leaves.uploadFile != null && emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength>0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName))
    {
        emp_leaves.fileNameOrig = Path.GetFileName(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName);
        emp_leaves.fileContent = new byte[emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength];
        emp_leaves.uploadFile.InputStream.Read(emp_leaves.fileContent, 0, emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength);
        Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"] = emp_leaves.uploadFile; //saving the file in session variable here
    }
    else if (Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"] != null)
    {//if re-submitting after a failed validation you will reach here.
        emp_leaves.uploadFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"];
        if (emp_leaves.uploadFile != null && emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength>0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName))
        {
            emp_leaves.fileNameOrig = Path.GetFileName(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName);
            emp_leaves.uploadFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
            emp_leaves.fileContent = new byte[emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength];
            emp_leaves.uploadFile.InputStream.Read(emp_leaves.fileContent, 0, emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength);    
        }
    }
//code to save follows here...
}
```

Finally within my edit view: here, i am conditionally showing the file upload control.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $("#removefile").on("click", function(e) {
    if (!confirm('Delete File?')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    $('#fileNameOrig').val('');
    //toggle visibility for concerned div
    $('#downloadlrfdiv').hide();
    $('#uploadlrfdiv').show();
    return false;
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
@model PPMSWEB.Models.emp_leaves @{ HttpPostedFileBase uploadFileSession = Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"] == null ? null : (HttpPostedFileBase)Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"]; } @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"
})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row">
  @*irrelevant content removed*@
  <div id="downloadlrfdiv" @((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.fileNameOrig) && (Model.uploadFile==n ull || uploadFileSession !=null)) ? "" : "style=display:none;")>
    <label>Attachment</label>
    <span>
            <strong>
                <a id="downloadlrf" href="@(uploadFileSession != null? "" : Url.Action("DownloadLRF", "emp_leaves", new { empLeaveId = Model.ID }))" class="text-primary ui-button-text-icon-primary" title="Download attached file">
                    @Model.fileNameOrig
                </a>
            </strong>
            @if (isEditable && !Model.readonlyMode)
            {
                @Html.Raw("&nbsp");
                <a id="removefile" class="btn text-danger lead">
                    <strong title="Delete File" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign">  </strong>
                </a>
            }
            </span>
  </div>
  <div id="uploadlrfdiv" @(!(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.fileNameOrig) && Model.uploadFile==n ull) && !Model.readonlyMode ? "" : "style=display:none;")>
    <label>Upload File</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.uploadFile, new { @type = "file", @class = "btn btn-default", @title = "Upload file (max 300 KB)" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.uploadFile)
  </div>
</div>
}
```